# Calling users from angular to node (MEAN) is sending only email and _id to angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, mean

I'm using the following code ..

```
// Node.js
router.get('/users/all', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    User.find({some query}).select('firstName lastName email').then((users) => {
        res.send(users);
    });


//Angular Service
let opts = { headers: this.getCommonHeaders(), params: new HttpParams() };
return this.http.get(getUserDataUrl, opts)
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          // here is the problem
          console.log(response.json());
          return response.json()
        }),
        catchError(this.handleErrors)
      );
```

In the opts headers I have mentioned the data type:

```
  getCommonHeaders() {
    return new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'x-auth': this.getToken()
    })
  }
```

In the console.log(response.json()) I'm getting only email and _id in the array's object. Adding the same console.log(user) on node.js before res.send(user) is showing the entire data with firstName and lastName

Then I added .lean() to the User function. this allowed the rest of the firstName and lastName to appear. How do I get the entire data without converting them to plain objects?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like this is the problem. When you use find() method in mongoose, It gives an array. so you convert that array into json and send using res.send(). so when you access it using Angular. it may be crashing and not giving the correct format so try changing the code in node js like this. 
Instead of find() try using findOne() in mongoose like this. I assume you only intend to take one user from this query right ?

```
// Node.js
router.get('/users/all', authenticate, (req, res) => {
User.findOne({some query}).select('firstName lastName email').then((user) => {
    res.send(user); // there was a typo I changed it too. look in the question not user it was users.
});
```

Comment: Oddly using findOne is also giving me the same result. Even changed .send() to .json() ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use res.json("JSON Object"); instead of res.send()..

Else try to check the db using tool like robomongo

Comment: he says it's he tries the 1st part of your answer in the first place and it gives the full json with all required details..

Comment: I did just try res.json(users) instead of res.send(users) .. I do use robomongo to check the database. console.log in NodeJS gives the full result including firstName, lastName, email, _id ... but after sending it to the front end, most of the results are missing.

Comment: If you try to pass an object that you make. and not from the mongodb is it pass ok?
Like { firstName: "this is test string", lastName: "Last name test", email:"1234abc@gmail.com" }

Comment: Yes. And as I said... If I convert it to .lean() in mongodb, it works. Also If I convert each element of the mongodb result object from its array, convert it to .toObject and append it to another empty array ... let's say "result" ... and send it to the frontend, it works.